# Having trouble importing 3D assets into Android Studio using Sceneform plugin

Tags: android-studio, 3d, augmented-reality, sceneform

I am trying to import a 3D asset into android studio to use with Sceneform. When I use the Sceneform plugin to generate a new Sceneform asset, nothing occurs, no errors or outputs to the terminal. I have tried changing the 3D asset form OBJ to GLTF and that does not help. I have tried directly adding the asset using sceneform.asset in the build.gradle and that also did not help:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.ar.sceneform.plugin'    
sceneform.asset('sampledata/models/Empty Cube.obj','default','sampledata/models/Empty Cube.sfa','src/main/res/raw/Empty Cube')
```

I am using Android Studio 4.0.1 and Sceneform 1.15.0